# integer function converting row names in to numbers

Tags: r, sapply

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eb9GZ.png)
I used to this

```
mydata3 <- data.frame(sapply(mydata2, as.integer))
```

But now I see that row names which is gene names, has been converted to number like 1-200). But I should point that same command I used sometime ago when it was working well. So I thought there are some problems with my file then i used old file on which this command was working but i am seeing same problem like gene name is converted in to number here is full script:

```
countsTable<-read.table("JW.txt",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=TRUE,row.names=1)
mydata2 <- countsTable/1000
mydata3 <- data.frame(sapply(mydata2, as.integer))
str(mydata3)
```

Please let me know.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide some sample data with your question.

Comment: Thanks for reply. i have added the picture of mydata2 and mydata3. hope you can see that after integer (mydata3) gene name has changed to numbers

Comment: Please don't post data as image. Use something like `dput(head(countsTable))` instead.

Comment: structure(list(V46 = c(221.76, 15181, 0, 7602.9, 676.99, 573.72
), V46.1 = c(217.52, 8921, 0, 7041.2, 615.74, 305.27), V46.2 = c(0, 
7275.9, 0, 6648.8, 215.99, 350.04), W30 = c(1006, 33038, 0, 7008.6, 
1278.9, 4844.3), W30.1 = c(755.83, 34975, 0, 7987.3, 1082.7, 
2629.9), W30.2 = c(342.09, 19059, 0, 4523.1, 538.67, 1077.8)), .Names = c("V46", "V46.1", "V46.2", "W30", "W30.1", "W30.2"), row.names = c("ACACA", "ACACB", "ACADVL", "ACTG1", "ADD1", "ADD3"), class = "data.frame") and after integer

Comment: structure(list(V46 = c(221L, 15181L, 0L, 7602L, 676L, 573L), 
    V46.1 = c(217L, 8921L, 0L, 7041L, 615L, 305L), V46.2 = c(0L, 
    7275L, 0L, 6648L, 215L, 350L), W30 = c(1006L, 33038L, 0L, 
    7008L, 1278L, 4844L), W30.1 = c(755L, 34975L, 0L, 7987L, 
    1082L, 2629L), W30.2 = c(342L, 19059L, 0L, 4523L, 538L, 1077L
    )), .Names = c("V46", "V46.1", "V46.2", "W30", "W30.1", "W30.2"
), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Please don't post data in comments. Use edit link to update your post instead.

Answer (score 1):

`sapply` works over columns of your data.frame `mydata2`, and returns respective output per column. as such, it does not return the row-names of your data.frame, so you either have to re-assign those, or re-assign the new column data into your original data.frame, like:

```
mydata2[] <- sapply(mydata2, as.integer)
```

Thus you can keep all of the original attributes.